# How to safely set, change, remove values of EFI variables

Tags: boot, uefi, bootloader, systemd, efi

After spending hours debugging a problem where `systemd-boot` started skipping its boot menu and in general ignoring its configuration file `/loader/loader.conf` (on the EFI partition), I've discovered that I can invoke the boot menu by pressing down some key at start-up, and that the problem is caused by certain EFI variable which I have apparently inadvertently created.  (I do not know how this happened, but the issue appeared shortly after I re-installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 on one partition.)

In particular, I've discovered that had the variable `LoaderConfigTimeout-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f` set to `0` somehow, which overrode the timeout defined in `/loader/loader.conf`, and I also had the variable `LoaderEntryDefault-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f` defined, which was overriding the default menu entry set in `/loader/loader.conf`.

See the bottom of ["systemd-boot UEFI Boot Manager"](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/systemd-boot/) page on freedesktop.org for the list of EFI variables used by `systemd-boot`.  Their values can be inspected with, for example

```
cat /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderConfigTimeout-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f
```

After I made the boot menu appear by pressing some key, and then pressed <kbd>d</kbd> twice to set and unset a new default entry, this removed my `LoaderEntryDefault-...` variable.  However, I am still stuck with `LoaderConfigTimeout-...`.  I know that I can change the timeout by using <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>(<kbd>Shift-t</kbd>) keys in the menu, which modifies `LoaderConfigTimeout-...`, but I want to remove it altogether, so that the configuration in `/loader/loader.conf` be used again.

What is the correct and safe way to modify and unset EFI variables, such as `LoaderConfigTimeout-...`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools to modify UEFI Variables in Windows/Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/421415/tools-to-modify-uefi-variables-in-windows-linux)

Comment: Similar, but somewhat confusing and not really duplicate, i think.  I am asking specifically about variables visible in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` under Linux, not about issues with legacy/non-legacy modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In systemd-boot, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Num -</kbd> enough times that the setting reaches zero, and one more time to unset it completely removing the variable.

On Linux, first use `chattr -i` on the /sys/… file to remove the kernel-applied protection, then use `rm` to delete the variable entirely.

In the UEFI Shell, use `dmpstore -d <name>` (with optional `-guid <guid>`) to delete a variable (see documentation in [UEFI Shell Spec 2.0](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_Spec_2_0_Errata_A.pdf#page=124), page 113).

Comment: Indeed, i've just discovered it myself that `Shift-t` does the job for `LoaderConfigTimeout-...`.  About removing arbitrary EFI variables with `chattr -i` and `rm`, how safe is it?  How can I know which variables are safe to remove?  See, for example, the discussion about [issue #2402](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2402) for `systemd` on GitHub.

Comment: Search for its name and/or vendor guid. If you find documentation about what it's doing, decide whether that's an important function. If you don't, then assume it's used by the firmware for possibly critical purposes.